Something is blocking Ahrefs bot on my WordPress site
I have a client with a WordPress site and I'm working with her to improve it overall. We've redesigned it, revamped content, relaunched it and we're getting more traffic.
However, Ahrefs cannot load the robots.txt file. To be clear, our site's robots.txt contents are not blocking Ahrefs as a bot in the rules, rather the request is timing out and never responds. This is odd because I can load the robots.txt file in my browser, Google can open it and I can verify Google is viewing the Robots file and using the stated Sitemap files to crawl the site successfully. I can also go to other 3rd party tools that will successfully load our Robots.txt file.
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/wpo-plugins-tables-list.json

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.rss

But Ahrefs shows it's timing out and not responding. The WP site has All-in-One SEO plugin installed. I do not see anything in here about blocking access to Ahrefs, and if it was - they would have likely put that inside the Robots file itself.
I have looked through all of the plugins and I don't see any settings or configuration that is blocking IPs or specific bots.
I have looked through CPanel and no IPs are being blocked. I have checked .htaccess and see no explicit rules blocking Ahrefs bot or specific IPs.
I have contacted the company running the web server and they stated that they do not have any IP restrictions on the server.
Where else can I check for possible configurations that would block this bot from loading the site?

I had the same issue. I disabled all the plugins, cleared the cache and then ran another audit. It was able to correct the issue. I then turned my plugins back on. WordPress plugins can cause issues with ahrefs and aduits
